# Is it possible to create some kind of virtual private cloud between my AWS apis/lambda and a non-AWS server provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

Right now I'm using AWS lamba and AWS EC2 and I'm relying on VPC to share data between a lambda function and a server when lambda needs something from the server.
With the right settings in Secure Groups the server accepts only requests from that special lambda and I don't have to do secure the connection between the two because it's like the server and the lambda function are the only two things in their network.

But I'm trying to move my server to another provider, and this means i have to find a way to secure the server

My question: is there something like a VPC I can create between lambda and a server hosted somewhere else AWS? what kind of tecnologies do i need?

I started looking for VPNs and certificates

Comment: Can I ask... _why_ are you moving your server to another provider? Is it to save money? Because a secure solution between two sites is likely to incur additional cost, which could defeat your original goal. You could also consider not using AWS Lambda, so that everything is on the new provider.

Comment: VPN would not be appropriate because Lambda function are transient. Why is an authenticated HTTPS API request from Lambda to external server not sufficiently secure?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein both learn something and save money. I'd like to migrate the server in order to learn what technologies are available and what's needed to link servers and services that have to communicate over internet

Comment: @jarmod. I was hoping for some kind of service or technology like Secure Groups to decouple network security from the server. anyway I'm open to suggestions and to learn network security for servers. the problem with the latter is that it's a really big topic and it's easier to screw up

Comment: I presume you mean Security Groups (which are EC2/VPC stateful firewalls). You could build a [VPN between these two environments](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/build-ha-vpn-connections-google-cloud-aws) and route the Lambda requests over that VPN, but it's added complexity and cost.